# SilverStripe TInyMCE configuration requires a refresh to take effect

Tags: php, tinymce, silverstripe

We have built out our own version of the tinyMCE editor in SilverStripe. The only issue is that you need to hit refresh for our custom configuration to be loaded. Once it has been refreshed once, it sticks for the rest of the session.

Our set up is as follows:

BolierplateWYSIWYG.php

```
class BolierplateWYSIWYG extends Extension {

    protected function defaults() {
        $defaultEditorConfig = HtmlEditorConfig::get('cms');
        $defaultEditorConfig->setOptions(
            array(
                'theme'                        => 'advanced',
                'priority'                     => 1,
                // More config options
            )
        );

        return HtmlEditorConfig::get('cms');
    }

    public function getConfig() {
        return $this->defaults();
    }
}
```

Then, inside of Page.php we have the following:

```
... page functions ...

public function getCMSFields() {

    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

    // Update WYSIWYG
    $digital360Wysiwyg = new Digital360WYSIWYG;
    $digital360Wysiwyg->getConfig();

    ... Page CMS configuration ...
```

Inside of our boilplate.yml we have:

```
HtmlEditorField:
  extensions:
    - BolierplateWYSIWYG
```

How do I get this new configuration to load without requiring a page refresh?

Comment: > "The only issue is that you need to hit refresh for our custom configuration to be loaded."

Answer (score 1):

Like @assertchris mention, my PR https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/pull/4259/files has now been merge so you can easily have multiple TinyMCE configs which should help you with you extension.

Setup your `HTMLEditorConfig` in `_config.php` like

```
HtmlEditorConfig::get('default')->setOptions....
HtmlEditorConfig::get('fancy')->setOptions....
```

Since you have to have an extension, you could have something like:

```
class BolierplateWYSIWYG extends Extension {
  public function setEditorConfig($name = 'default')
  {
    HtmlEditorConfig::set_active($name);
  }
}
```

The you can use it like this when setting up your CMS fields

```
$digital360Wysiwyg = new Digital360WYSIWYG;
$digital360Wysiwyg->setEditorConfig();
```

or

```
$digital360Wysiwyg = new Digital360WYSIWYG;
$digital360Wysiwyg->setEditorConfig('fancy');
```

This should work fine. Although be careful when changing some of the editor options like `mode`, as this can cause your refresh issue. an you shouldn't have to change `theme` or `priority`?

Answer (score 0):

Might want to check this pull request: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/pull/4259

Comment: Looks promising, will it address the issue of the configuration only applying when the page is refreshed? I don't want multiple configurations on the page, I just want my configuration options for the standard editor to work without needing to refresh the page.

Comment: The configurations are injected into JavaScript on page load. Are you trying to change the configuration dynamically, or just have a custom configuration?

Comment: Not dynamically, just trying to customise the 'out of the box' WYSIWYG.

Answer (score 0):

You can customise your `HtmlEditorField` by calling `setOptions` in your _mysite/*config.php*:

```
HtmlEditorConfig::get('cms')->setOptions(
    array(
        'theme'                        => 'advanced',
        'priority'                     => 1,
        // More config options
    )
);
```

This will work without the need to refresh a CMS page.

Comment: While this isn't an extension like you had in your question, I hope this still meets your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I have used that method in the past, my issue is that we have created a boilerplate module that we use in all of our builds. As such, I need this to work as part of a module / extension.

Comment: You should be able to put this in the `_config.php` in your boilerplate module folder. Would that suffice?